# Civicrm and wordpress user registration after admin approval

Tags: wordpress

so the scenario is that i am using civi profiles for civicrm contact and wordpress user creation by enabling "WordPress user account registration option?" in profile's advance setting.

I am also using 2 other plugins to control access of wordpress users which are "**Ultimate Member**" and "**User Role Editor**". ultimate member plugin has a option by which when a user register it needs admin approval. i have selected that option but its not doing what it has to do. when ever a user register i automatically approves it.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking here. If the plug in Ultimate Member isn't working like it is supposed to - we might not be able to help with that. But if you give us a better idea of your use case for an account approval step maybe we can help with some Civi pointers.

Comment: my issue is that civicrm profiles are not working in conjunction with ultimate member. is there any way to fix this? or is there any way by which when i create account by civi profiles it ask for admin approval in both civi and wordpress

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would need to create a custom plugin which would play role to interconnect the two features, ultimate member plugin account verification method and automatic wordpress user creation through profile.

In that custom plugin, you would need to use '[hook_civicrm_post](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_post/)' hook which will get called every time a DB write is done, make sure to put an if condition right after the hook function definition to make plugin run only when account gets created and in that if condition make call to the function that performs account verification process in 'Ultimate Member' plugins, more detail on how to call a function of wordpress plugin from another wordpress plugin can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57043/how-can-i-call-a-function-from-one-plugin-within-another-plugin).

Hope this solution will help you.

Comment: This is correct!  I had a similar problem with Drupal and the Domain Access module.  When a user was created through a Civi profile, the Domain Access module couldn't set their permissions.  I wrote [domain_civicrm](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/domain_civicrm) to solve that problem - you need a similar plugin.

Comment: sadly I don't know how to create a custom plugin. anyways thanks : )